# UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute is not working for forbidden (403)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, error-handling

When I specify 404 as a http result code, `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` is working like expected.

[image]

When I specify 403 as a http result code, `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` is not working like expected. Somehow it works like I have specified `UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects`.

[image]

I need the behaviour of `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` for all status codes in range of 400-600, including 403.

The configuration code:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/error/403/");
                options.LoginPath = "/account/signinrouter/";
            });
    //...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    //...
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
    //...
}
```

The action code:

```
public IActionResult NotFound()
{
    return base.NotFound();
}

public IActionResult Forbidden()
{
    return base.Forbid();
}
```

Comment: `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` doesn't detect the 403, because it's not a 403 when it comes back up through that middleware. It's a 302 and therefore outside of the range 400-600.

Comment: I am trying to override that behaviour on CookieAuthenticationandler now.

Comment: You can do that with [`OnRedirectToAccessDenied`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.onredirecttoaccessdenied?view=aspnetcore-2.2). Let me know if you need help with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, thanks to @Kirk

Adding this code to `AddCookie` does the trick.

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 403;

    return Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

This is the original event handler method, I don't care the `Location` header, so I have omitted the related code, you may not want to.

```
public Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task> OnRedirectToAccessDenied { get; set; } = (Func<RedirectContext<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, Task>) (context =>
{
    if (CookieAuthenticationEvents.IsAjaxRequest(context.Request))
    {
    context.Response.Headers["Location"] = (StringValues) context.RedirectUri;
    context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
    }
    else
    context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});
```