# 401 and 403 Custom Error page not displaying when App deployed to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a ASP.NET Core WebApp.  AuthN and AuthZ within the App is handled by AAD - if a User tries to hit a page in the site and are not in the correct AAD group I am attempting to use the middleware and render and NotAuthorized page.

In my Startup class in the Configure method I have the following code:

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
            {
                appBuilder.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
                appBuilder.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            });

            app.UseHsts();
        }
```

For local IIS Test I commented out the if block and deployed to my local IIS and in my AppSettings only added an AAD group that I know I am not a member off - when I hit the URL Locally I get the following which is working as I expect:

[image]

The code in my ErrorController is as below:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [Route("error/404")]
    public IActionResult ErrorNotFound()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("error/401")]
    [Route("error/403")]
    public IActionResult ErrorNotAuthorized()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index", Activity.Current?.RootId);
    }
}
```

However when I deploy the same code to Azure I am getting the following when I hit the same URL -

[image]

Is there something I am missing as too why the customer 403 page I have is not being rendered when my app is deployed to Azure?

Comment: Hi would you kindly try my way would be happy if it resolved your problem. Good luck

Comment: hi @MdFaridUddinKiron - I am not sure this will be the same as what I need - you are handling generic error exceptions with the middleware - I am attempting to use Status Codes to handle specific routes for 401 and 403 - which works when I publish locally to iis - just not when I host on Azure

Comment: Ah, I thought if I could help you. May you case was different as I thought

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - no probs - appreciate the effort

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - I think it is something like in this answer - a 403 is not detected by the middleware but as a 302 - just not sure how to get the same behaviour in my app - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56868673/usestatuscodepageswithreexecute-is-not-working-for-forbidden-403

Comment: So problem resolved ha ha

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out with this answer -

[ASP.net-core 3.0 - Is it possible to return custom error page when user is not in a policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58629209/asp-net-core-3-0-is-it-possible-to-return-custom-error-page-when-user-is-not-i)

Basically 401 or 403 are not handled by the middle ware so wrote my own custom